# What is the technique where you perform a "u-substitution" on a limit called?

Tags: calculus, limits

I say u-substitution for lack of a better term, it's somewhat similar to u-substitution in integrals but a bit different. For example, if you want to evaluate:

$
\lim_{x \to 0^+}x^{x^2}$

What you can do to solve this is: set $u = x^2$

Then solve the original limit (in this case $x$ going to zero from the right) with $u$ as the function:

$\lim_{x \to 0^+}u$

Which gives zero since $0^2 = 0$

And then solve the limit where $u$ approaches the result above (in this case zero) of the substituted function (in this case $x^{x^2} = x^u$ since $u = x^2$):

$\lim_{u \to 0^+}x^u$

And then you get $1$ since anything to the power of zero is $1$.

Is there a name for this technique? I'd like to learn more about it and practice it but all I get when I search for "limit substitution" is things about *direct* limit substitution, not this stuff.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you calculate the logarithm of the limit first:

$$\ln \lim_{x \to 0^+}x^{x^2}=
\lim_{x \to 0^+}\ln(x^{x^2})=\lim_{x \to 0^+}x^2\ln x$$

Comment: Well that's another way to solve the problem yes, but I was wondering just about the way I solved the question, not the solution itself. What is the name of the technique I used to solve the question? Thanks for the response by the way!

Comment: It gives the right answer in this particular case, but it's not a valid method. Try to solve $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(2x)/x$ using the same method